# reprepro: keeping "older" packages in the index

Tags: reprepro

Whenever I add a new version to a reprepro repository, it forgets and deletes the older package by default. I want to keep it, so I use `--keepunreferencedfiles` to the config:

```
$ reprepro --keepunreferencedfiles includedeb stable /path/to/jjdns_0_4.5_amd64.deb 
jjdns_0.4.5_amd64.deb: component guessed as 'main'
Exporting indices...                                                                     
1 files lost their last reference.                                                       
(dumpunreferenced lists such files, use deleteunreferenced to delete them.)
```

Now I have `jjdns_0.4.5` referenced, and `jjdns_0.4.4` in the repo, but not in the index:

```
$ grep -A1 "Package: jjdns" dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages
Package: jjdns
Version: 0.4.5
```

Question: how can I add `0.4.4` back to the index? Or, even better, not remove it when uploading `0.4.5`?

Comment: This is somewhat of a limitation for apt. It doesn't really have this multi-version in a single repo support.

Answer (score 1):

the last version of reprepro supports multiversioning
https://github.com/ionos-cloud/reprepro